# Error with the code in Java Classes and Xml files

Tags: android

I was working in my project running the aplication in the emulator to test changes and all that , then suddenly my clases and xml files code just go crazy like in the images , it is imposble continue to work in the project , funny thing is , i still can compile it and run it in the emulator , but the code in the classes and xml files just continue the same

I try to rebuild , clean , invalidate cache and restart but nothing seem to work for the moment

The project has this libraries

Volley , rxjava2 , retrofit2 , gson:2.8.0 ,{greenrobot (greendao 3.1)(eventBus 3.0)}

my LoginActivity class

```
<component name="libraryTable">
  <library name="Gradle: com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0@jar">
    <CLASSES>
      <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0/c4ba5371a29ac9b2ad6129b1d39ea38750043eff/gson-2.8.0.jar!/" />
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC />
    <SOURCES>
      <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0/baf95d8519fc1a11d388f8543cb40cd2bb9d66dc/gson-2.8.0-sources.jar!/" />
    </SOURCES>
  </library>
</component>
```

Xml file

```
/* AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY.
 *
 * This class was automatically generated by the
 * gradle plugin from the resource data it found. It
 * should not be modified by hand.
 */
package android.arch.lifecycle.livedata.core;

public final class R {
}
```

[image: Error in classes]

[image: Error Xml file]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like it´s a bug in android studio 3.2.1 , i just uninstalled it and install the 3.1 version , problem is solved